# Why does Cloud Shell fails to clone tutorial code?

Tags: google-cloud-shell

> All 3 .NET tutorials have now failed me.  Frustrating.  Step 5 of "[Handling sessions with Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/session-handling-with-firestore)" merely offers a "Go to Cloud Shell" button that fails when a clone is requested in the Cloud Shell with:
> 2023/07/02 01:15:25 Cloning https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-dotnet into /home/kramffud/cloudshell_open/getting-started-dotnet
> Cloning into '/home/kramffud/cloudshell_open/getting-started-dotnet'...
> fatal: Remote branch master not found in upstream origin
> 2023/07/02 01:15:26 failed to resolve path '/home/kramffud/cloudshell_open/getting-started-dotnet': No such file or directory
> Error occured

My actual current project name is, "My Bookstore".  From the injected Cloud Shell command lines, it seems to me that "getting-started-dotnet" is from the 1st tutorial I attempted and not this one.  No idea what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug in the URL to open tutorials.  Instead of branch *main*, the URL specifies *master*.  You can use the following link to open the tutorial sample:

https://cloud.google.com/console/cloudshell/open?git_branch=main&git_repo=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-dotnet&working_dir=Sessions

I will follow up with the team to get it fixed.